Is it possible to use a VCS without access to the actual website files?
I'm working with a CMS to create websites. It's not an open-source CMS. To create a webpage I paste my code in different tabs, one of html, one for css, one for head, one for body bottom and one for body top.
However I don't have access to the actual files I'm creating, for example index.html or content.html
I'd like to have a VCS, that allows me to the basics like create branches, pull requests and merge the code. Under this less than ideal scenario is there a way to do this?
I'm very lost and I'd appreciate any help. Thank you!
I haven't tried anything since I just have user access

You can use VCS only if you convert your HTML/CSS fragments to files. Either manually (which is possible but quite tedious) or if you find an API in your CMS that would allow you to upload/download fragments.

I would assume the created files are likely not generated as static files, but instead are generated when the site is accessed.
